# How to present a new UIViewController without an action?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to push a new `UIViewController` if a user is logged in, but I don't really understand where it fails.

```
    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
    {
        returnUserData()
        var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)

        var vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loggedInViewController") as! UINavigationController

        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
    }
```

Here's the error message:

`User Logged In
2015-05-10 16:35:18.010 noscrubs[32134:43488091] Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7f86dc282920> on <noscrubs.ViewController: 0x7f86dc279aa0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: In which method the if block is written?

Comment: You want to `push` or `present`? Both are different

Comment: Where in your code do you have this if statement? The error message is telling you that ViewController's view is not on screen, which I'm guessing means that you're tying to do this in viewDidLoad. If that's the case, you need to move the code to viewDidAppear.

Comment: it in the viewDidLoad function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're presenting a view controller too early. You should wait for the `viewDidAppear:` method to be called on your view controller before trying to present anything.

viewDidLoad is called before the view is displayed, which is accomplished by adding the view to the window hierarchy. After the view is loaded, then the view will be added and viewDidAppear is called.